# Snowflake : ROWID equivalent in snowflake for updates

Tags: sql, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Oracle we used to get the Row address with ROWID function to identify insert, updates from the source, if the source table doesn't contain Primary Key Columns. I want to migrate the same to Snowflake query, but getting a problem with the Update scenario, where as part of the rowid logic, the record which gets the updated value has the same rowid value for the initial record which got inserted in target, so it matches and consider the updated values from the below logic. But the question is how it can be handled using the snowflake logic ??

**Src:**

```
SELECT ROWID, CLMN_ID, CLMN_NUM, CLMN_EMP_NAME, CLMN_START_DATE FROM EMPLOYEE_SRC;
```

**Tgt:**

```
SELECT ROWID, CLMN_ID, CLMN_NUM, CLMN_EMP_NAME, CLMN_START_DATE FROM EMPLOYEE_TGT;
```

The original query to indentify which type of transaction (insert, delete or update record):

```
    SELECT  a.ROWID as ROWID_TGT, a.CLMN_ID, a.CLMN_NUM, a.CLMN_EMP_NAME,
    b.ROWID_SRC, b.CLMN_ID, b.CLMN_NUM, b.CLMN_EMP_NAME , 
    IFF ((a.ROWID_TGT)  IS NULL, ''I'', 
           IFF ((b.ROW_ID_SRC) IS NULL, ''D'', 
           IFF (a.CLMN_ID = b.CLMN_ID 
            AND a.CLMN_NUM = b.CLMN_NUM 
            AND a.CLMN_EMP_NAME = b.CLMN_EMP_NAME, ''IGNORE'', ''U''))) AS TRANSACTION_FLAG
FROM  EMPLOYEE_TGT AS a   FULL OUTER JOIN  EMPLOYEE_SRC AS b   ON  a.ORA_ROWID_TGT  =  b.ROWID_SRC;
```

We can achieve the insert and delete logic from the same sequence logic, but only the problem with the update scenario. I have tried the has method as well, but it will consider everything as new record itself.

Comment: I dont think there is a rowid function or equivalent in snowflake. Have you explored Snowflake Streams for Change tracking?

Comment: Have you tried ROW_NUMBER() ? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number

Comment: As the Oracle ROWID is a pseudo column I don’t understand how your original query could work - you’re joining records on completely “random” values, there’s no connection between records that may have the same ROWID in two different tables

Comment: Oracle ROWID is a physical storage location that describes which data block the row is contained in. It cannot be used for joins and generally should not be used as a pseudo primary key because there are circumstances under which *it can change*. If you need a primary key then create one, even if it is just an otherwise meaningless numerical sequence. It will solve your problem *and* be permanent *and* be database agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

the ROWID pseudocolumn returns the address of the row. Oracle Database rowid values contain information necessary to locate a row:

The data object number of the object
The data block in the data file in which the row resides
The position of the row in the data block (first row is 0)
The data file in which the row resides (first file is 1). The file number is relative to the tablespace.

Snowflake dose not have this Rowid preset or even if it is present it is not exposed to the users. One option you can do is to identify the columns making up the unique
rows and use them to  write the update statement.